# React Native Design Approach for App Walkthrough

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react-native app and I would like new users to experience one of those slider walkthroughs that explains the app and how to use it, but then never show it again.

What is the best approach to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Navigator to achieve this. Push the sliding view into the Navigator, then when you want to exit out of it then use replace(route) function of the Navigator.

The replace(route) method of navigator replaces the current scene with the new route

> replace(route) - Replace the current scene with a new route

Comment: Thanks. Now how does the app know when to do the TutorialView? If I just replace it, then next time the app opens it will do the tutorial view again. I only want it to run the sliding TutorialView once.

Comment: I think AsyncStorage is what you are looking for. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: Thanks. Async storage was exactly what I needed, I just implemented my nav/routes totally backwards and it kept re-rendering when it shouldn't have. I can add the code once I finish.